# Run a batch-file on login of non-admin user as admin

Tags: windows, script, batch-file, administrator

I need to run a batch script as an administrative user while an non administrative user is auto logging in. Is that possible?

If I use `runas` I can't insert the password.

The script uses an `devcon` command to enable an device.

Comment: Check "use highest privileges" and make sure the task is setup to use the credentials of a user that has appropriate permissions. P.S. login is different from boot.

Comment: I believe Seth is correct here...configure the scheduled task with those options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx to Seth and Stephen R. the scheduled Task was, what I needed. Another solution is to ad the script in the group policies (gpedit).